# How to properly use the Homeassistant websocket npm library and use "const require" rather then "import"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, home-assistant

Can someone please explain how to use this Home Assistant Node JS websocket library? The creator hasn't provided a completely working example for NodeJS and so I have two issues with it.

https://github.com/filp/homeassistant-ws

https://www.npmjs.com/package/homeassistant-ws/v/0.2.2

When I put "`import hass from 'homeassistant-ws';`" into my NodeJS app as author specifies, i get:

`"SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"`

normally I experience something like with the home-assistant puller library, It looks like this:

```
   const HomeAssistant = require('homeassistant'),
   const hass = new HomeAssistant({
        host: 'http://127.0.0.1',       // Home Assistant IP address
        port: 8123,                     // Home Assistant port number
        token: 'my-token',
        ignoreCert: true                // above is Home Assistant long lived token 
    });
```

But this library have to use Import? why its like that? is there a way to just use require like in my example?

Anyway, i dont normally use "package.json" file for my project but I made this file and put this inside:

```
{
    "type": "module"
}
```

Ok so now seems to be going a step further, but now getting errors like :

```
  import hass from 'hass';
  ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Identifier 'hass' has already been declared
```

if i remove this line (`import hass from 'hass';`) and keep only the line (`import hass from 'homeassistant-ws';`) , then i get:

```
hass({
^
TypeError: hass is not a function
```

I used many libraries already including the NPM home-assistant library with no issues but I have no idea how to make this work. I love this minimalist approach and using websocket for HA.

Can someone provide a working example? And share how to import the library using the "Const Require" way? So i dont have to use package.json file? I'd really appreciate it.

My example:

```
import hass from 'homeassistant-ws';
process.setMaxListeners(0);
main();

async function main() {
  // Establishes a connection, and authenticates if necessary:
  const client = await hass({
     token: 'my-token', 
     host: '10.20.0.5',
     port: 8123,
    });

  // Get a list of all available states, panels or services:
  await client.getStates();
  await client.getServices();
  await client.getPanels();

  // Get hass configuration:
  await client.getConfig();

  // Get a Buffer containing the current thumbnail for the given media player
  await client.getMediaPlayerThumbnail('media_player.my_player');
  // { content_type: 'image/jpeg', content: Buffer<...>}

  // Get a Buffer containing a thumbnail for the given camera
  await client.getCameraThumbnail('camera.front_yard');
  // { content_type: 'image/jpeg', content: Buffer<...>}

  // Call a service, by its domain and name. The third argument is optional.
  await client.callService('lights', 'turn_on', {
    entity_id: 'light.my_light',
  });

  // Listen for all HASS events - the 'message' event is a homeassistant-ws event triggered for
  // all messages received through the websocket connection with HASS:
  //
  // See https://developers.home-assistant.io/docs/api/websocket/ for details on HASS events:
  client.on('message', (rawMessageData) => {
    console.log(rawMessageData);
  });

  // Listen only for state changes:
  client.on('state_changed', (stateChangedEvent) => {
    console.log(stateChangedEvent.data.new_state.state);
  });
}
```

Comment: "SyntaxError: Identifier 'hass' has already been declared" means you use the keyword `hass` twice in your file.

Comment: right of course but when i remove the redundant declairation i get. `TypeError: hass is not a function`

Comment: I assume the two lines declaring `hass` aren't identical. Instead of removing a line, try picking 2 different names if you're working with 2 different things.

Comment: that exactly what i tried and thats when i get `TypeError: hass is not a function`

Comment: Ok, please share a complete example of the file that generates this error. (do so by editing your question)

Comment: ok, im just directly copying from the NPM example, then removing or swapping code block because im not sure which ones go together. I provided the link earlier.

Comment: The example on NPM does _not_ have 2 "hass" declarations, so you must have changed something to get the first error. If you _are_ using the example _exactly_ from the page and get the `hass is not a function` then it's possible the package is broken and you should log a bug report.

Comment: But if the npm package is not broken, you need to share the exact code that causes the error in order for someone to understand what's wrong.

Comment: right ok, i added my example to my question. the author does have two different examples using import, one being `import hass from 'hass';`. i think its a mistake? also im not sure if im supposed to call `main()`. if i dont, nothing happens, but if i do i get `TypeError: hass is not a function`

Comment: I added a potential workaround to this issue. Hope it works!

Answer (score -1):

I *think* the bug is in the package, and it expects you to use Typescript with specific settings for that snippet to work.

I believe if you change this line:

```
import hass from 'homeassistant-ws';
```

to:

```
import * as hassImp from 'homeassistant-ws';
const hass = hassImp.default;
```

it *may* work.

Comment: with or without the changes you suggested, if i don't call `main()` the app immediately ends with no messages. But if i call `main()` i get `TypeError: hass is not a function`. Original example never calls `main()`

Comment: I think even with no homeassistant server running (which i do have available) it still should produce some kind of connectivity error or something. Well anyway, i really appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: @sceptre357 yes, do call `main()`. If my exmaple failed, i think it might be time log an issue with this project.